pylint scanning is different between Windows and Linux
I have a Python project that I want to scan with Pylint. Once I run pylint **/*.py I get different results between Windows and Linux machines, under the same Python and Pylint versions, same working directory, and same .pylintrc config.
pylint 3.2.7
astroid 3.2.4
Python 3.12.4 

For example, when I run pylint --verbose **/*.py on Windows I get Checked 23 files, skipped 0 files but on Linux I get Checked 6 files, skipped 0 files (Windows scan is right, I have 23 Python files in the repo).
I don't understand why the number of files it finds is different. Any idea why this is happening?

On Linux the **/*.py is expanded by the shell before it is passed to pylint. Windows doesn't do this so pylint is doing the expansion. I don't believe bash supports the **/ construction to recurse into subdirectories. You want pylint doing the expansion, so quote the argument such that the shell passes it along instead of expanding it. '**/*.py'

Or on Linux: pylint \find . -name *.py``.

@kindall that's called globstar which expands to all files (and folders if having the / suffix) recursively

@nrofis did you enable globstar?

@phuclv it seems so, yes, after moving the scan to pylint it was solved

pylint . --recursive should discover your python files the same way under Windows and Linux.
